# How to display HTML section full screen?

Tags: html, css

I was successful in making navigation bar full width, and I want to do the same with HTML sections, but can't get it right.

I've tried setting all margins and padding to 0 (which gets me closer to full screen display), and setting left and right property on individual sections (excluded from this code because it doesn't seem to change anything).

Could it be a problem with CSS position property? Because navigation bar has position: fixed; and sections don't have position property set (I guess it's static).

Below is full HTML & CSS code used in my project.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Marko+One&display=swap');
$my-black: rgb(64,64,64);
$my-white: rgb(192,192,192);

*, html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Marko One', Verdana;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    background: $my-white;

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-left: 1em;
        font-size: 2em;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: $my-black;
    }

    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
}

#welcome-section {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: $my-black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    h1 {
        color: $my-white;
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}

#projects {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: purple;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;

    h1 {
        color: $my-white;
        font-size: 2em;
    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: gold;
        padding-top: 0.5em;
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
}

#contact-section {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: $my-black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;

    h1 {
        color: $my-white;
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav id="navbar">
      <a href="#welcome-section">Intro</a>
      <a href="#projects">Work</a>
      <a href="#contact-section">Contact</a>
    </nav>
    <section id="welcome-section">
      <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    </section>
    <section id="projects">
      <h1>Projects</h1>
    </section>
    <section id="contact-section">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Set the viewport to a height of 100%, in css this is `html, body { height: 100%; }` To avoid overflow by using padding or border, add `*, html, body { box-sizing: border-box; }`

Comment: after putting everything inside a fiddle it seems to work, but this is not css, this is scss. dont try running scss as css because that seems to be the issue of the snippet above in the question: https://jsfiddle.net/1e0t4s2c/

Comment: In the flow of html all sections are stacked. So by default it is not possible to use the serction as 'layers'. To do this you have to use `position absolute;` with a `top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%;`

Comment: @bron I've tried both of your suggestions, but none of them solve my issue. When I run my snippet on jsfiddle, it looks good, but when I run my snippet through Visual Studio Code and with Angular (ng serve command), I get white space on both left and right side of the body (except nav).